# Navigation bar <ul> instead of table

Tags: html, css, navigation

I know that using tables in html as part of the layout is bad practice, and so would like to know how to style the example you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLBYe/) using the `<ul>` element instead of a table. All spacings and font sizes need to remain the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried using display: inline but that didn't work

Comment: If you add the HTML and CSS you have tried so far then we can offer some constructive advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

(The idea is to use the `box-sizing` property in order to be able to set `width: 25%` safely.)

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#nav li:first-child {
    border: none;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dLBYe/8/

Comment: @Alp Yea, can't wait for Firefox to finally drop the `-moz-` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

How's this example (no JavaScript needed): **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLg7P/)**

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#';">Home</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#';">About</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#';">Gallery</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#';" style="border:none">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul {
    display:inline;
    font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

li {
    float:left;
    width:24%;
    text-align:center;
    border-right: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    list-style:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

BTW you had a small error in your CSS for the font which I corrected in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Those `onclick` attributes violate DRY.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I'm just re-using what the OP posted. It's not what I would do and the OP never said it needed to be DRY style. I think he's more interested in layout than JavaScript.

Comment: 1. Why `display:inline` on `ul`? 2. Why are you using inline styles? 3. Why aren't you handling your floats correctly? 4. Why do you say no javascript needed when it obviously needs it  `window.location.href`?

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: The display:inline is optional and just makes the nav/menu fit better in some layouts. I'm only using an inline style on the last list item to get rid of the border. Obviously you could use JavaScript or a CSS3 attribute to also do that. I have no idea what you mean by why aren't I handling floats correctly -- please explain.The window.location.href code is from the OP and not mine.

Comment: Isn't `onclick="window.location.href='#'"` exactly the same as `href="#"`?  I would recommend against using either.  If you need links that do nothing the best way is to serve the page with a proper `href` and then either capture the event with JS and/or replace the `href` with JS to `javascript:void(0)`.  Always remember your most important visitor has javascript turned off.

Comment: `display: inline` will make it fit better in some layouts? Inline style is not necessary if you put the border on the left and remove the first border using `first-child` (CSS2) and if you don't know about clearing floats yet then [read this](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/).

Comment: @BrettPontarelli Noticed in this case the onclick is in an li tag, which href does not work in.

Answer (score 1):

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dLBYe/9/

HTML:

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#'">Home</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#'">About</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#'">Gallery</li>
    <li onclick="window.location.href='#'">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    font: 20px, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.navbar > li {
    width: 25%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar > li:first-child {
    border: none;
}

.navbar:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: i'd go for a `border-left` to set borders then `.navbar > li:first-child{border:none}` to remove the first li's border to avoid using additional classes.

Comment: `display: inline-block` is not supported in all browsers

Comment: Setting the width to `24%` is suboptimal. Note that you can safely set it to `25%` if you additionally set `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

Comment: Are you sure, i tried it and it does not seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dLBYe/7/

Comment: @Alp Are you using Firefox? As for now, a `-moz-box-sizing` copy is needed since Mozilla yet has to switch to the standard name.

Comment: @Alp However, there is a different problem in that demo. When you use `inline-block`, there will be spacing between the individual elements (a few pixels), which means that you want to be using `float:left` instead. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 0):

Given a list like below there are two ways I know of.

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

You can use float left/right

```
li {
    float: left; /* or right */
}
```

Or display inline/inline-block *(n.b. this way leads to problematic sizing)*

```
li {
    display: inline; /* or inline-block */
}
```

You can alter the padding / margin / width to suit see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TSTUF/)

**Edit:** Full example without using border-size [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/TSTUF/4/)

```
ul {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: -1px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}

ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Example using `display: table` which is now a third way I know to achieve this effect :-) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/TSTUF/3/)

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

ul li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: this won't work with borders because the width would be something more than 100%

Comment: As I said the OP can alter padding or margin or width to suit, they could also use `box-sizing: border-box` or `margin-right: -Npx` etc lot's of options nothing is ever definitive [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/TSTUF/1/) to illustrate